# How to prevent Intellij destroying code, again

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, editor, code-intelligence

Given :

```
function hide(){                                                                       
       displayer.hide(error);  
}
```

Refactored the **function** name yields:

```
function refactored_to_new_name() {
             displayer.refactored_to_new_name(error);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent intellij from doing this.

Why does it think it has the right to **assume** it is intelligent?

These kinds of refactorings should never fail, but intellij does it way too often. It assumes things.

**Search in comments and strings are disabled.**

You might not be able to reproduce this, but it **doesn't mean it didn't just happen**.

Comment: Which editor you use? intellij comes on multiple...

Comment: @Dekel Ultimate 16.x something.

Comment: Either it is a reproducible bug, or it is a user error, my bets are on a user error.

Comment: @Meo How can that be a user error? And why do you assume the editor knows better. I was able to reproduce this in another script. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Then post a reproducible example.

Comment: can't reproduce; full code snippet would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly is not a correct behavior. If you are able to reproduce this issue as you say, the best thing you can do is to file an issue in [Jetbrains's issue tracker system](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Here is a guide how to [submit issues correctly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reporting-issues-and-sharing-your-feedback.html#d477011e118):

1. Open the IntelliJ IDEA tracking system at
   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ .
2. If you are not yet registered, do
   it.
3. Click Create issue.
4. On the page that opens, choose IntelliJ IDEA
   from the Project drop-down list.
5. Describe your problem and provide a
   brief summary of it in the Description and Summary fields
   respectively.
6. If necessary, attach a screenshot that illustrates
   your problem.
7. Click Create issue when ready.